# Passing an integer using Intent not working in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an Intent set up that opens up a new activity and I wanted to pass an Integer value. The opening of the activity works but as soon as I use a code to pass on the value app crashes.

Here is my code of main activity  -

```
public void onFinish() {
  tap1.setClickable(false);
  Intent i = new Intent( Single.this, FinalScore.class);
  i.putExtra("kee1", count);
  startActivity(i);
```

Value is fetched using below code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_score);
    TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tx.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kee1"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need cast `int` value to `String` for setting to `TextView`:

you can use following code:

```
tx.setText(""+getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kee1"));
```

add `""`  to first of the value do this for you.

or you can use following code to cast that:

```
String value =  String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kee1"));
tx.setText(value);
```

you can use `Integer.toString();` too as @Duncan mentioned on comment.

Comment: Or `Integer.toString(...)` might be nicer. I hate to see `""+...` in code.